# How do I use a non-Vue custom Web Component in a Vue Component (without Webpack)?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
            <jrg-element></jrg-element>
        </div>
        <script type="module">
            import Vue from "//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js";
            import {ShadowElement, CREATE_ELEMENT} from "//unpkg.com/@jrg/ui/target/jrg-ui.esm.mjs";
            class JrgElement extends ShadowElement {
                constructor() {
                    super("<h1>CustomElement</h1>");
                    this.render();
                }
            }
            CREATE_ELEMENT("jrg-element", JrgElement, {});
            const app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run I get....

[image]

If I comment out the Vue portion everything works fine. How do I use Custom elements with Vue?

**Update**

I tried updating to ...

```
CREATE_ELEMENT("jrg-element", JrgElement, {});
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['jrg-element']
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
       message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

But I still get...

[image]

The result is the Vue element renders but the custom element does not.

[Full Code](https://github.com/jrgleason/jrg/tree/EXAMPLES_FRAMEWORK_INT/jrg-ui/examples/vue)

**Update 2**

I tried waiting until the dom is loaded like...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  });
});
```

But same outcome

Comment: Vue version in use ?

Comment: Latest version available

Comment: Well from the code it seems you are using Vue 2.x (`app = new Vue(`)...

Comment: Actually it seems to be vue 2 as the deafult release in unpkg

Comment: FYI this is a url //unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.esm.browser.js so you can use that to see version

Comment: yep, its 2.6 (as 3.0 release is still "hidden" after `@next`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225627/discussion-between-jackie-and-michal-levy).

Answer (score 0):

Vue templates (content of `app` `div` in your case) are compiled by Vue template compiler and expects all custom elements are Vue components and properly registered. In order to tell Vue that you are using some non-Vue custom element (Web Components API), you need to configure compiler.

Vue 2.x

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['jrg-element']
```

Vue 3

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag === 'jrg-element'
```

[The docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#autonomous-custom-elements)

Comment: So when I add the 'Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['jrg-element']' I get 'Uncaught DOMException: Operation is not supported'. The Vue element seems to render ok but the Web Component does not I will update example thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Vite 2, it's like this:

```
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: tag => tag === 'jrg-element'
        }
      }
    })
  ],
```

<sub>Source: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1312</sub>